# Encrypt with Public Key and decrypt with Private Key using elliptic-curve cryptography

Tags: cryptography

everybody.
Is it possible to perform public key encryption flow for elliptic-curve cryptography?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography

I need to implement the following scenario:

1. Alice generates a message.
2. Alice encrypts it with Bob's public key.
3. Alice sends a message to Bob (via an insecure channel).
4. Bob gets the message.
5. Bob can decrypt this message only with his private key.

I can't find a proper method inside the tweetnacl lib (https://github.com/dchest/tweetnacl-js). Could somebody can direct me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you're looking for help/advice implementing this kind of scheme you might be better served asking on stackoverflow. I'd second camp0's answer below that it might be a better idea to find an existing implementation than writing your own. You can check [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=elliptic+curve+implementation+javascript&oq=elliptic+curve+implementation+javascript) too.

Comment: I agree. StackOverflow is the most suitable place for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be looking for an **ECIES** implementation. [Here](https://github.com/bitchan/eccrypto) is a random JavaScript library that seems to support it.

Elliptic Curves do not support a encryption primitive like RSA does. There is EC ElGamal but is not worth it due to the small key sizes and the amount of overhead of ElGamal.

To use curves with encryption you need to use hybrid encryption. ECIES is hybrid encryption: offline ECDH key agreement together with symmetric encryption performed using the derived secret key.

---

Note that ECIES is **not** well standardized. You may have to choose your own key derivation function, stream cipher or block cipher and mode of operation. For the key derivation method you could choose HKDF where available. AES in GCM mode seems a sane choice today for the cipher (the 12 byte IV may be set to zero or to a value derived from the "shared secret" as well). Libraries that support ECIES will probably have their own idea on what ECIES should look like, but beware of compatibility issues...

Comment: BTW, I managed to convert keys from ed25519 to ed25519curve. And curve supports encryption, it means that it is possible to do that. You can check it here:
https://github.com/evgeny-s/stellar-sign-encryption

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the encryption method in the documentation that you linked to for tweetnacl-js?
https://github.com/dchest/tweetnacl-js#naclboxmessage-nonce-theirpublickey-mysecretkey

> **nacl.box(message, nonce, theirPublicKey, mySecretKey)**
>
> Encrypts and authenticates message using peer's public key, our secret key, and the given nonce, which must be unique for each distinct message for a key pair.
>
> Returns an encrypted and authenticated message, which is nacl.box.overheadLength longer than the original message.

You would use the recipient's public key as the third argument to the above function.  You would use your own private key as the fourth argument.  The library takes care of message integrity by creating a signature of the encrypted message, signed by your private key.

Comment: I don't want other keys to be involved in the encryption flow. If it had publicKey only, it would suit for me.

Comment: If you're not interested in authenticating the origin of the message, use a second, fixed (or throwaway) public-private key pair. Use the throwaway private key to "sign" the message and simply ship the corresponding public key along with the encrypted message so the recipient can authenticate and decrypt it.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you go to an easy library that makes the work for you, I specially like the python ecdsa module (https://github.com/warner/python-ecdsa), is easy and not complicated. Also read about how EC works will help you in make your decision.

Comment: ECDSA is a signature algorithm, it doesn't do encryption.